# Search all subdirectories with 0 files

Tags: command-line, bash

I want to print the names of all subdirectories that contain zero files (they may contain subdirectories). The following works for the current directory:

```
$ ls -p | grep -v / | wc -l | \
  xargs -I % test % -eq 0 && pwd
```

I think that there might be a more elegant solution, any suggestions? And how do I have to change it to recurse through all subdirectories?

I have a test structure: test/test1/test4 and test/test2/test3/test5. The only file is in test/test1. I want to run the command in the basis directory (test/). The results are supposed to be: test/ ; test/test2/ ; test/test2/test3/ because those are the directories that only contain subdirectories but no files. Additional accceptable would be the empty endpoints test/test1/test4/ and test/test2/test3/test5.

Comment: `find . -type d -empty` should do that.

Comment: @jos no, it only lists empty directories but it doesn't include any directories that include only subdirectories but no files. Those are exactly those I am looking for.

Comment: it should not traverse the directory structure? its only 2 directory deep?

Comment: @bac0n it should, that is the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using fgrep to filter out directories with files:

```
$ find -type d | \
  grep -xFv -f <(find -type f -printf %h\\n)
```

Comment: @jamacoe please edit this information into your question

Comment: This works now, nice idea!

Comment: @bac0n Many file and directory names contain special characters (a music library) so I received the error message "xargs: unmatched single quote; by default quotes are special to xargs unless you use the -0 option". Adding -0 to xargs and -print0 to the latter find solved it, so now the correct answer is:  find -type d | grep -xFv -f <(find -type f -print0 | xargs -0 -n 1 dirname)

Comment: I remove xargs alltogether and used printf instead

Comment: This is a pretty neat idea and works great as long as you have no newlines in your file names ;-) Not very common, but used in a script it might introduce vulnerabilities. Using it in a script needs some comment or you won't know what this does some thime later ;-)

Comment: shh.. its a feature :)=

Comment: @bac0n Thank you. That has the elegancy I was looking for. I am too fresh here to upvote your answer, but I learned a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
find . -type d -exec bash -c 'files=$(find $1 -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f | wc -l) ; [[ $files -ne 0 ]] && exit 1 ; exit 0' script {} \; -print
```

The `bash -c ...` is just a "small" script that returns 0 or 1 after checking for files in the directory.

Comment: This is the first working solution and it shows the right output :) But imho to include a script lacks elegance.  Perhaps it is possible with some kind of recurse switch.

Answer (score 0):

A different approach to the problem:

```bsh
# Enable advanced glob
shopt -s globstar
# Enable matching hidden files (.*)
shopt -s dotglob
for d in **/; do
   nofiles=true
   for f in "$d"/*; do
     [ -f "$f" ] && nofiles=false && break
   done
   [ $nofiles = true ] && echo "$d"
done
shopt -u globstar
shopt -u dotglob
```

Loop through all folders, inside them loop all items and check for files.

Not the shortest script, but will not fail on newlines, spaces or alike in your file names. And it is easy to read also when you look at it again after 5 years ;-)

Comment: looping through directories was my first idea given the approach in my question. And true, much easier to read. Personally, I prefer one liners like bac0n's and I am going to comment it thoroughly :)